# In a data type definition, how can I 'name' similar references?

Tags: haskell, types

I can define a tree like so:

`data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)`

Let's say I want to remind myself that the first tree is the left tree, and the second is the right tree.

I tried

`data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (L (Tree a)) (R(Tree a))`

which failed. So Haskell knew `Branch` was a constructor, but couldn't do the same for `L` or `R` given this statement.

I tried to help with:

```
data L a = L a
           deriving (Show)

data R a = R a
           deriving (Show)

data Tree a =
  Leaf a | Branch (L (Tree a)) (R (Tree a))
  deriving (Show)
```

This works, but now I can have an `L "whatever"` without it being a left branch. And more code than it seems I need to remind myself that the first tree is the 'left' and the 2nd is the 'right'.

Is there a nicer way of doing this?

Comment: Are you wanting the reminder during pattern matching, or when looking at the type?

Comment: Phantom types?  `data L; data R; data Tree side a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree L a) (Tree R a)`? Not sure if this really helps.

Comment: @bheklilr I'm completely new to Haskell, and it's not clear to me how I would define a type in a way that disagreed with pattern matching. So I don't really know how to answer you.

Comment: `data Tree a = TrLeaf a | TrBranch (Branch a) ; data Branch a = Branch { leftBranch :: Tree a, rightBranch :: Tree a }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want a record:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch { l :: Tree a, r :: Tree a}
```

Then you can have a

```
Leaf 3
```

or a

```
Branch { l=Leaf 4, r=... }
```